# Issue while trying to submit ajax form in django

Tags: python, jquery, django

**Server Side Code**

```
@csrf_protect
def Authenticate(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return JsonResponse({"success": False})
```

**Form**

```
<form class="row" id="frmLogin">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form#frmLogin").validate({
        rules: {
            "username": {
                "required": true
            },
            "password": {
                "required": true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.post({
               url: "/authenticate/",
               contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8;",
               dataType: "json",
               data: JSON.stringify({
                   "username": $(form).find("[name='username']").val(),
                   "password": $(form).find("[name='password']").val(),
                   "csrfmiddlewaretoken": $(form).find("[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val()
               }),
               async: true,
               success: function(response) {
                    
               }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Payload Info**

[image]

**Same Origin Message**

[image]

**Error Message**

[image]

Comment: Try not doing the `JSON.stringify`, just posting using a normal dictionary. Usually you only need to stringify it when it’s some crazy nested stuff and Ajax usually handles all the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`X-CSRFToken` header](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request) when you send a POST request with AJAX:

```
$.post({
   url: "/authenticate/",
   contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8;",
   dataType: "json",
   async: true,

   data: JSON.stringify({
     "username": $(form).find("[name='username']").val(),
     "password": $(form).find("[name='password']").val(),
   }),

   headers: {
    'X-CSRFToken': $(form).find("[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val()
   }    
})
```

Comment: Could you please show me where is the `X-CSRFToken` header in your screenshot? I don't see it, only a csrf cookie. Both are needed.